# Is it possible to avoid the warning of undefined offset PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, undefined-index

I know the undefined offset gives out *warning instead of error* but I want to know is there any possible way to avoid this kind of warning to pop out? I intend to write a function to test the undefined offset because I think that writing multiple similar `if-else` condition to test offset could be much work to be done.

```
function testOffset($item){
        if(isset($item)){
            return $item;
        }else{
            return "Nothing here!";
        }
    }
$array1[] = "Hello!";
echo testOffset($array1[1]);
```

In this case the function is work well but the warning will also pop out the moment I assign the unset element into function. Anyway to work around with it?

---

*I purposely set the checking index to 1 to prove the function is working well*

Comment: How about array_key_exists? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: Array indexing starts at 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of handling this problem, but depending on what you are trying to do you could do:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {}
```

If you are just trying to get 1 element based on the key, you should just go with [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
$array1[] = "Hello!";
echo (array_key_exists(1, $array1)) ? $array[1] : "No key";
```

Comment: I guess I didn't consider well into this because I used this in the same project by checking whether the _string-based key_ exists in the array or not... Thanks ya!

Comment: If they are string based keys, you just add " " around the key

Answer (score 4):

You can try function like this

```
function issetOr($arr, $key)
{
    if (isset($arr[$key])) {
        return $arr[$key];
    } else {
        return "Nothing here!";
    }
}
$array1[] = "Hello!";
echo issetOr($array1, 1);
```

Or if you wan't to check for key existence use

```
function issetOr($arr, $key)
{
    if (\array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        return $arr[$key];
    } else {
        return "Nothing here!";
    }
}
$array1[] = "Hello!";
echo issetOr($array1, 1);
```

[Demo online](https://3v4l.org/KJNgR)

Comment: Much better than using @ also.

Comment: I realize this is better than using @ although both way achieve the same result I was looking for in the early. @ means to suppress the warning notice but it is hard to tell that **only** undefined offset is the only error in other case.

Comment: Good @gitguddoge

Comment: You can use this native function http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-exists.php its more better if you want other solution

Answer (score 4):

If your using PHP 7+ you can use [null coalesce](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to make the whole thing just a one liner...

```
echo $array1[1] ?? "Nothing here!";
```

Answer (score 1):

For escape warning and notice in php you can use simply an @

```
function testOffset($item){
    if(isset($item)){
        return $item;
    }else{
        return "Nothing here!";
    }
}
$array1[] = "Hello!";
echo @testOffset($array1[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I knew it would come out the warning notice but I just want to simply ignore it!

Comment: Using @ is not a good practice since it suppresses the error or warning which will be hard to debug for developer.

Comment: You are welcome, @AfrazAhmad here the developper assume the responsability, its an focntionallity who offer PHP for a lot of situations

Comment: There is other solution like array_key_exists or other @gitguddoge if you want we can chat and i will give you other solution.

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet really thanks for this answer but mleko's answer is better in this way. I'll still upvote for your answer anyway!

Comment: You can use this native function http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-exists.php its more better if you want other solution

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using offset 1, which is not exist,

you can do a simple code fixing by using the below:

```
function testOffset($item){
        if(isset($item)){
            return $item;
        }else{
            return "Nothing here!";
        }
    }
$array1[] = "Hello!";
echo testOffset($array1[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i intend to do it in this way to try the function

Answer (score -2):

**You can handle this by php array_values builtin function:**

1. `$yourArray = array_values($yourArray);`

This will rearrange your array indices
e.g. 
 You have a array like this:

```
 $a[0] = '...'
 $a[4] = '...'
 $a[7] = '...'
 $a[8] = '...'
 $a[9] = '...'
```

after using array_values

```
 $a[0] = '...'
 $a[1] = '...'
 $a[2] = '...'
 $a[3] = '...'
 $a[4] = '...'
```

Comment: By the mean _stops the script execution_ means it will stops the script if this is in the loop right?

Comment: the warning does not actually stops the script as I tested earlier just now tho